# Extract Unique numbers from a group of numbers in the same cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have several numbers in a cell seperated by a comma. The cell next to it has similar numbers but some are unique. I need a formula to extract the unique numbers and place them in another cell. I tried conditional formating but no luck. The function can't seem to highlight the unique cells.

| HHC 1 | HHC 2 |
| --- | --- |
| 12,18,67 | 12,18 |
| 45,32,55 | 55,32,26 |

Comment: Given your data set, what would you expect for results? What version of Excel are you using? And what OS (Windows or Mac)?  Do you want to return just the numbers in HHC2 that are not in HHC1?  Or do you want to return the unique numbers from both?  In other words, should the results be  `row 1: nothing or 67`; `row2: 26 or 45,26`

Comment: I want to return the unique numbers in another cell. So when you compare HHC1 to HCC 2 on the first line the unique number is 67. I want that to show up on the blank cell. I am using Microsoft Excel 2016 which doesn't have the unique function.

Comment: OK That means you don't have the TEXTJOIN function either.

Comment: Yes I dont have the TEXT Join function but I believe I can add it to a module in VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is what you want for results:

[image]

you can use this formula:

```
C2: =TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,A2,B2),",","</s><s>")& "</s></t>"," ",""),"//s[not( .=preceding::* or .=following::*) ]"))
```

I know you don't have the `TEXTJOIN` function in Excel 2016, but you mentioned in the comments that you can add it as a VBA module, so I suggest you do that.

Since you might be using VBA anyway, you can do the entire task using VBA:

```
Option Explicit
Function UniqueSingleOccurrence(ParamArray vals() As Variant)
    Dim dict As Object, v, w, x, y
    
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

'Store all the values in an Array List
For Each v In vals
    Select Case TypeName(v)
        Case "Range"
            For Each w In v
                For Each x In Split(w, ",")
                    y = Trim(x)
                    If Not dict.exists(y) Then
                        dict.Add y, 1
                    Else
                        dict(y) = dict(y) + 1
                    End If
                Next x
            Next w
        Case "String"
            For Each x In Split(v, ",")
                y = Trim(x)
                If Not dict.exists(y) Then
                    dict.Add y, 1
                Else
                    dict(y) = dict(y) + 1
                End If
            Next x
        Case Else
            MsgBox "Typename = " & TypeName(v) & vbLf & "Needs code revision"
            Exit Function
    End Select
    Next v
    
'remove the duplicated values
For Each v In dict.keys
    If dict(v) > 1 Then dict.Remove (v)
Next v

UniqueSingleOccurrence = Join(dict.keys, ",")
    
End Function
```

Comment: it worked for that one cell, but i want to drag it down and get many others. Great so far

Comment: oh, disregard I found the problem. Formating on some numbers were mismatch. They all need to be the same. It works. Thank you!!!

Comment: @Turbo95 Glad to help. Since my answer seems to be what you require, kindly mark it as Accepted.  See [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).